# Indian Passport stolen with valid visa

Tags: schengen-visas, lost-documents

I was in Barcelona in month of March, 2019 and my Indian passport with one year multiple entry Schengen visa was stolen. I have returned back to India on Emergency Certificate issued by the Indian embassy in Madrid.

Now I have to travel again to Spain next month.  Should I apply for a new visa on my new passport or can I get the same lost visa extended on my new passport?

If the answer is yes, whom should I contact & where?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to apply for a new visa.  There is no procedure in the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) for extending visas even when they haven't been stolen and even when the same passport is presented with the application.  The only option is to submit a new application for a new visa.

The fact that you have a previous visa and that you complied with its conditions will weigh favorably in your new application.